# BigQuery to count if two record values is greater than or equal the values in their columns and find percent overall

Tags: google-bigquery, countif

Let say I have a table of millions of records resulting from a simulation, below sample

```
    TO  Sim DUR Cost
    1   1   20  145
    1   2   24  120
    1   3   27  176
    1   4   30  170
    1   5   23  173
    1   6   26  148
    1   7   21  175
    1   8   22  171
    1   9   23  169
    1   10  23  178
    2   1   23  172
    2   2   29  152
    2   3   25  162
    2   4   20  179
    2   5   26  154
    2   6   27  137
    2   7   27  131
    2   8   28  148
    2   9   25  156
    2   10  22  169
```

how to do the calculation in BigQuery to find the percent count of rows that are satisfying two conditions. (i can do a UDF but I would like it to be all in SQL statements)

The excel equivalent to the new calculated column would be =countifs($C$2:$C$21,">="&C2,$D$2:$D$21,">="&D2,$A$2:$A$21,A2) / countif($A$2:$A$21,A2)

the results would look like

```
TO  Sim DUR Cost    f0
1   1   20  145 0.90
1   2   24  120 0.40
1   3   27  176 0.10
1   4   30  170 0.10
1   5   23  173 0.30
1   6   26  148 0.30
1   7   21  175 0.30
1   8   22  171 0.40
1   9   23  169 0.50
1   10  23  178 0.10
2   1   23  172 0.10
2   2   29  152 0.10
2   3   25  162 0.10
2   4   20  179 0.10
2   5   26  154 0.10
2   6   27  137 0.30
2   7   27  131 0.40
2   8   28  148 0.20
2   9   25  156 0.20
2   10  22  169 0.20
```

Comment: Can you explain how to interpret the excel function?

Comment: It can be explained if the table is copied to excel where the column titles are in cells A1 to D1, the excel formula will then be in cell E2 and dragged to fill all the table rows.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(a).*, COUNTIF(b.dur >= a.dur AND b.cost >= a.cost) / COUNT(1) calc
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
USING (to_)
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', a)
-- ORDER BY to_, sim
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row to_ sim dur cost    calc     
1   1   1   20  145     0.9  
2   1   2   24  120     0.4  
3   1   3   27  176     0.1  
4   1   4   30  170     0.1  
5   1   5   23  173     0.3  
6   1   6   26  148     0.3  
7   1   7   21  175     0.3  
8   1   8   22  171     0.4  
9   1   9   23  169     0.5  
10  1   10  23  178     0.1  
11  2   1   23  172     0.1  
12  2   2   29  152     0.1  
13  2   3   25  162     0.1  
14  2   4   20  179     0.1  
15  2   5   26  154     0.1  
16  2   6   27  137     0.3  
17  2   7   27  131     0.4  
18  2   8   28  148     0.2  
19  2   9   25  156     0.2  
20  2   10  22  169     0.2
```

Note: I am using field name `to_` instead of `to` which is keyword and not allowed to be used as column name

Comment: Thank you Mikhail for your prompt response. i have run the SQL in bigquery for a table size of 75000 rows (having 75 TOs each having 1000 Sim) but the query takes 7 min 4 sec elapsed time. is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: another observation that i noticed, is that when the `project.dataset.table` is a temporary table from a sub query, the answer for calc would be incorrect. however when i create a table from the sub query, it gives me the correct calc but slow. is there a reason why reading from a subquery will be wrong?

Comment: hard to answer without knowing what your subquery is  - but it can be if subquery has some non-deterministic values which when you save 'em as table are same for both `a` and `b` joined tables, but when you do it on fly they actually produce different sets - just a guess - if you want to dig deeper - you should post new specific question on that with all specific details on your `sub-query`, etc. as of performance -  I would say - yes, probably above query can be optimized, but without real data it is hard to test it